# White blocks when scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have finished a website, and saw that there are white blocks when scrolling - [site here](http://musicians.solid-themes.com). Happens on mobile and on desktop. It happens only on first load. Does it mean the page has not yet fully loaded? If so, I could show longer the loading screen, but need to know, how do I know when the page is loaded. If it's not because of that - what's causing that?

To reproduce: Open it in a browser and after loading screen use the mouse scrollbar to scroll down (using the scrollbar on the screen can't reproduce it).

Open it in a mobile browser, scroll down the page - here we can see it pretty obviously.

Not sure why you cannot reproduce it. Please see attached screenshot from my mobile. This happens when scrolling up and down. [image]

Comment: I don't see any white blocks. What do you mean?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @KobyDouek  agreed no white block is there on scroll.

Comment: By the way, You page is **extremely heavy**. Consider downsizing the images.

Comment: Added an example screenshot how it looks from the mobile. This happens when scrolling up/down. Not sure about the code, since this is not a single page related issue, but happens on all pages.

Comment: The browser is struggling to paint the page. I counted 31 touch event listeners that are not set to passive.

Comment: @Ihazkode what could be the solution?

Comment: _"Not sure about the code, since this is not a single page related issue, but happens on all pages"_ That doesn't matter to us. We need a [mcve] **in your question**. Work on paring your problematic code down to a bare minimum example and post it in your question please.

Comment: I am seeing it on my high end mac.... so not sure what you have running on that site that is causing it.... Do you have code listening to scroll or something?

Answer (score 3):

On empty cache, your page makes 34 requests and its total page size is 23.7 MB. Out of which, there are 18 requests for images, and total download size for images is 23.3MB. Are you trying to load this site on user's mobile.

Downsize or web-optimize your images. The white blocks are coming because the container for the images is not completing load as the images are still being downloaded. Also, mobile cache sizes are lesser than computer cache sizes.

Checkout the chrome network tab on first or empty cache load of the site and you can see.

Once images have loaded, and your page is visited again. Its total data transfer is 5.7 KB but there are 34 requests still and stuff is rendered from cache. You can try to add far future expiry to your images if they will remain the same on your site.

Comment: You're mostly correct, but the squares would persist even if the page is fully loaded on low-end devices. This is *jank* at its extreme. The white squares are delayed browser painting caused by constant repainting that's hindered by touch event listeners that are not set to passive and other scroll hindering design elements.

Comment: White blocks are appearing in my web-browser also on using slower connection speed. This page is taking over a minute to load first time on 8MBPS WIFI line. Now, DOM content is loaded in 4.something seconds. But complete page load takes minutes.