# Page goes white and renders slowly when scrolling on cordova Android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I'm experiencing sluggishness in rendering the contents of a scrollable list in my android app built using [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). You can view an example of the problem in [this video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/28525986/130440941-8efde087-1b6c-41cc-a0e4-cbedd95ed7fd.mp4), it's from a sample app containing a minimal reproduction of the problem. You can see in these screenshots:

[image: segment of screen painting slowly]
[image: segment of screen fully painted]

Segments of the screen are slow to paint while scrolling, and the problem seems to particularly affect the text at the bottom of the scrollable list. The source code for the sample app is at [this github repo](https://github.com/CodeWithOz/cordova-bad-web-workers/tree/feature-npdn), and you can download the APK [here](https://github.com/CodeWithOz/cordova-bad-web-workers/actions/runs/1158200728). There are a number of [similar stackoverflow posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=white+blocks+on+the+page+when+scrolling+website+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk03wLcG5BI3hsxOq5WGfAbKLYYG_vg:1629541612211&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4yMTH88HyAhXDBGMBHSnqCtoQrQIoBHoECAUQBQ&biw=1299&bih=641) about this problem, but so far I've not found a workable solution. In particular [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885937/white-blocks-when-scrolling-the-page) seems to report the exact same problem, but you can see in the source code above that there are not very many requests going out. More so, my video was recorded after the images had fully loaded, so the problem is not because the images are still loading as the main answer suggested. In fact in the main app where I have this problem, the slow scroll starts happening after the images have fully loaded, not before. A comment in that thread also mentions that slow scroll may also be due to touch event listeners that are not passive, but there are no touch event listeners in the sample app as you can see in the source code.

Some other things to be aware of:

- optimizing the images may help with the problem, but I'm not sure of this yet as I haven't been able to get the optimization working correctly from the cdn. Nevertheless, I think optimization will at most minimize the problem rather than fix it, but please correct me if I'm wrong
- in the `index.css` file you will notice that I use `content-visibility: auto`, which can cause some of the images to be re-rendered while they scroll in/out of the viewport. That actually minimizes the problem even if it seems like it worsens the problem. When it's removed the problem gets worse.
- You will also notice some hardware acceleration using `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` and `backface-visibility: hidden`, which are intended to push items into a separate layer for compositing. Some people recommend hardware acceleration as a fix for this problem, but it doesn't help in this case. More importantly, hardware acceleration solves other problems in the real app, and even when I remove it this problem still persists.

I'd greatly appreciate your insights/suggestions, thanks! :)

Comment: Have you ever developed any solution to this problem? I'm having a very similar problem, only on Android. During scrolling of long lists, the page flickers like some elements were not rendered fast enough. I have tried the `content-visibility` trick but I think it has made it worse

Comment: Sorry no clear fixes. Consider reducing the size of your DOM. If you have a long list, consider moving other things that are not visible out of the DOM. This can be tricky to achieve but it's worth a shot, it helped us.